# What is the difference between poll(),pollFirst(),pollLast(),removeFirst() and remove() methods which are used on a LinkedList object in Java?

Tags: java

I have a LinkedList object.

I want to apply these 5 methods on my LinkedList object.

```
LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();

1) Object o = ll.poll();
2) Object o = ll.pollFirst();
3) Object o = ll.pollLast();
4) ll.remove();
5) Object o = ll.removeFirst();
```

When I use poll(),pollFirst(),removeFirst() those are removing the first item of the list.

Any one can tell me what happened when I use these methods on my LinkedList object? and what are the differences between these 5 methods those are applicable on a LinkedList object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the Javadocs for the methods?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is asking for information that's well documented.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the naming of the methods is quite obvious telling what do they do.

Only bit confusing thing is why 2 methods doing same thing in poll() and pollFirst(). For that see below -

LinkedList implements two interfaces - Queue and Deque. And Deque extends from Queue.
Now, Deque has defined the method - Deque#pollFirst() and inherited the method - Queue#poll().
So, LinkedList has basically these two methods defined for the two interfaces it implements.

Comment: why does deque need to have pollFirst() if it already inherits poll() from queue?

Comment: Deque is double ended queue. Double ended queue allows both push and pop from both head and tail of the queue. Hence pollFirst() is a separate method. Similary it contains pollLast as well.

Comment: LinkList directly implements List and Deque interfaces not Queue and Deque.

Answer (score 14):

The Javadoc tells you :

> poll() : Retrieves and removes the head of the queue represented by this deque (in other words, the first element of this deque), or returns null if this deque is empty.
>
> remove() : Return the head of this list, throws NoSuchElementException if this list is empty
>
> pollFirst() is the same as poll().
>
> pollLast() return the last element of this list, or null if this list is empty
>
> removeFirst() is the same as remove()

Comment: N.B. pollLast() also removes the last element of the last if not null